# how to remove digest cycle from angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am familiar about the digest cycles in angularjs and how they work. my question is, can we remove digest cycle from angularjs and still be able to build angular app; if yes how can we remove them. I also want to know how can we delay the digest cycles.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do that ? maybe your problem can be solved without the need to remove the digest.

Answer (score 1):

No, the digest cycle is the fundamental part of AngularJS that makes it work (two-way data binding and all that.) Why use AngularJS then if you want to break it into something that is no longer AngularJS?

The digest cycle simply creates "watcher" abstractions to allow data to flow back and forth between the views and data layers.

If you don't want this, then I would suggest not using AngularJS, as you would be using bloated code for no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is already provided by other users, which is no.

However we get to control when our data goes to view and when they don't.

For example an instant data-binding by default looks like this:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='data'>
{{data}}
```

What if we want to delay it, by say 0.5 seconds?
We can separate the view model and assign it the value when it is appropriate.

```
<input type='text' ng-model='data'>
{{viewData}}

$scope.$watch(function(){
    $scope.data;
}, function(){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.viewData = angular.copy($scope.data);
    }, 500);
});
```

Or only display only when a button is clicked.

```
<input type='text' ng-model='data'>
<button ng-click='click()'>Click me!</button>
{{viewData}}

$scope.click = function() {
    $scope.viewData = angular.copy($scope.data);
}
```